# QTcpServer: Send HTTP/1.0 200 OK to connected client

Tags: c++, qt, shoutcast, qtcpsocket

I set up a QTcpServer to listen to a Shoutcast stream. The newConnection()-signal gets fired as it should:

```
connect(tcpServer, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SLOT(handleClientComm()));

void IcecastServer::handleClientComm(){
    QTcpSocket *clientConnection = tcpServer->nextPendingConnection();
    qDebug() << clientConnection->write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n" ) << endl;
    clientConnection->flush();
}
```

How do I send HTTP 200 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must extract QTcpSocket object from QTcpServer with nextPendingConnection() call when the newConnection() signal was emitted. And then you must call writeData() on the extracted QTcpSocket object.

The key here is that Listening socket (QTcpServer) is only responsible for creating Connection Sockets (or QTcpSocket) each time a new client connects. And the QTcpSocket is responsible for the actual communication with a specific client.

Maybe you can be more specific what exactly does not work for you and what have you tried? It would also be nice if you could provide us with wireshark PCAP if something does not seem to work as expected?

Comment: Thank you. It works now, I had to remove the spaces between the newlines.